# Blazor preventDefault on submit form

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

Inside my `EditForm`, I want to prevent that the user submits the form by pressing the `Enter` key.

I have tried the following, but didn't work.

```
<button type="submit" @onkeypress:preventDefault>Save</button>
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want to submit when having the cursor in a textfield and then press "enter"? Ifnthe case that the submit button has focus and then press "enter" then you want to submit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have got this working by just putting 2 submit button's in the `EditForm`, with the first one disabled.

```
<button type="submit" disabled style="display: none" aria-hidden="true"></button>
<button type="submit">Save</button>
```

Comment: Interesting find. This works because "the browser should find the first submit button in the form and click it."  It is tricking the Browser but it should run correctly everywhere.

Comment: This works for me only if the second button's type is **button** and not _submit_.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer for JavaScript, it's also a plea not to do it: [The Enter Key should Submit Forms, Stop Suppressing it](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2013/01/01/enter-should-submit-forms-stop-messing-with-that/)

If you still want to do this: make sure your form has more than one input and *no* submit button.

```
 <button type="button" @onclick="MySubmit">Save</button>
```

and then handle your validation in MySubmit, using an EditContext or whatever.

Comment: This is not the answer to the question. The question is how to prevent the default behavior of the submit button. This is enabled in Blazor, and even the OP is wrongly trying to use it. What you suggest requires the OP to completely change the layout of his form, and control the validation manually: lots of work and knowledge...  There is a simple solution for this. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working code sample, run it and see for yourself that the form is not submitted when you hit the Enter key:

Enter a value into the first field, then second field, then tab out, and hit Enter. Now look what is printed in the Output window... Do you see the "Submit..." string ? I think not.

```
<h1>My articles</h1>

<p>Leave me a comment</p>
<p>Note that the Save button is located outside of the EditForm component.</p>
<EditForm  Model="Model" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name: </label>
        <InputText Id="name" Class="form-control" @bind-Value="@Model.Name"> 
                                                             </InputText>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Model.Name)" />

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="body">Text: </label>
        <InputTextArea Id="body" Class="form-control" @bind- 
                                         Value="@Model.Text"></InputTextArea>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Model.Text)" />
    </div>
    <p>
        <button type="submit" @onkeypress="@KeyHandler" 
                              @onkeypress:preventDefault>Submit</button>
    </p>
</EditForm>


@code
{

    private Comment Model = new Comment();

    private void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Submit...");
    }

    void KeyHandler(KeyboardEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Key == "Enter")
        {
           return;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("KeyHandler...");

    }

}
```

Comment: I get the "Submit..." but not "KeyHandler..." https://ibb.co/pK8H6Kf

Comment: The code is robust and it should work. I ran it on a couple of computers, server side and client side and it works perfectly well. I'm going to report this fantastic issue in github, and leave there a link to your question. This may be related to quantum phenomenon, not to software.

Comment: Just tried it with a fresh new project (latest preview), but same issue

Comment: Could you please upload your complete app into github, so I can download and run it as is...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  <button type="submit" @onkeypress="@KeyHandler" 
                                  @onkeypress:preventDefault>Submit</button>
```

And this:

```
    void KeyHandler(KeyboardEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Key == "Enter")
        {
            return;
        }


    }
```

Comment: The form is still submitting